# jQuery find() returning an empty string in Google Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, firefox, google-chrome

I'm using jQuery to setup an Ajax request that grabs an XML feed from a PHP script and then parses some information out of the feed and inserts it into the DOM. **It works fine in Firefox; however, in Chrome, I am getting an empty string for the `title` element.**

Here's the basic setup of the Ajax request:

```
$.get('feed.php', function(oXmlDoc) {
  $(oXmlDoc).find('entry').each(function() {
    $(this).find('title').text();
    $(this).find('id').text();
    // do other work...
  }); 
});
```

For what it's worth, here's the PHP script that's grabbing data from the feed. I'm using cURL because I'm making the request across domains (and because it was a quick and dirty solution for the problem at hand).

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $str_feed_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $xml;
```

The XML data is being returned correctly and I can see the values of the sibling nodes in Chrome (such as `ID`), but, for whatever reason, I continue to get an empty string for the `title` node.

**Edit:** As requested, here's a fragment of the relevant XML:

```
<entry>
    <id>http://TheAddress.com/feed/01</id>
    <title type="text">The Title of the Post</title>
    <author><name>Tom</name></author>
    <published>2009-11-05T13:46:44Z</published>
    <updated>2009-11-05T14:02:19Z</updated>
    <summary type="html">...</summary>
</entry>
```

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but make sure that the xml is returned with the correct content type (text/xml). You can also set the dataType to xml at the [jQuery.ajax(options)](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options).

Comment: I ended up needing to specify the Content-Type as rss+xml in the PHP script. $.get() ended up working just fine after that.

Answer (score 2):

The page you have in the example XML has an HTML entity in the title.  This can cause issues.  Here is a [blog post](http://dtott.com/thoughts/2007/07/11/javascript-html-entities-title-attribute-headache/) I found on this issue.

I wonder if the same goes for other special characters...

The home page title looks like this:

```
<title>The Address Hotels + Resorts</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
It seems than Chrome don't handle html tag in ajax.
try changing "title" to "booktitle" in the XML and in the JS.