# Jquery filter URL

Tags: jquery, url, filter

I think that I am on the right track but I need your help.

I use this code to get my URL parameter

```
 function $urlParam(name){ 
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(name) != -1) {
        var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href); 
        return results[1] || 0; 
    }
    return 0;

} 


$(function() {
var $page='#'+$urlParam('id');

 });
```

And than I tried to filter that data with

```
$side_menu.find('> li > a').filter($page).click();
```

But this doesn't work.

Is there anything that I can do so I can filter data with $page variable?

If you need any more data I would be glad to provide it to you.

Thank you in advance,
Prokka

Comment: What "doesn't work"? $page contains a correct id and $side_menu.find('> li > a') finds elements but $side_menu.find('> li > a').filter($page) does not?

Comment: You figure it out :) For example if I put .filter('#Link1') it is working, but if I put .filter(page), and page = '#Link1' nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first off, instead of:

```
window.location.href
```

you might as well use:

```
window.location.search
```

as that is just the parameter part of the URL (the part you want).  Also, your variable:

```
$page
```

... the "$foo" variable naming convention is usually meant to be applied to jQuery object variables.  In other words:

```
var foo = "foo";
var $foo = $(foo);
```

So (unless you have your own, different convention) I think "$page" should really be named page .

As for:

```
$side_menu.find('> li > a').filter($page).click();
```

I can't tell for sure, but it looks like you're filtering on an id.  Is that correct?  If so, filter makes no sense; IDs are by definition unique on the page, so simply doing:

```
$($page).click();
```

is totally the same thing (even performance-wise).

> > But this doesn't work.
> >     Is there anything that I can do so I can filter data with $page variable?

Without knowing the value of your page variable it's hard to say.  I'd suggest adding this:

```
console.log($page);
$side_menu.find('> li > a').filter($page).click();
```

Well, if you're using Firebug or a browser with a console (if not ... you should be using Firebug ;-) but you could also just change it to "alert($page)").

When you do that, you should see what selector you're really using.  Most likely something is wrong with it.  If you don't see anything obvious, try adding:

```
console.log($page); console.log($($page));
$side_menu.find('> li > a').filter($page).click();
```

(the alert trick won't work for this one).  This should show you what elements (if any) jQuery selected using your selector.  Between this and reviewing the selector itself, you'll likely find the problem (and if you don't, maybe try playing around with running the commands in the Firebug console manually)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me :)

Unfortunately if I put only $($page).click(); nothing happen. 

I also add alert on link to find out value of $page variable and it is correct.

Further more I fixed my variable names as you suggested.

Thanks one more time :)

Comment: How did you hook up your onclick handler?  Did you do <a onclick="someHandlerFunction()">foo</a> or did you do $(thatA).click(someHandlerFunction); ?

Comment: For testing purpose I put

 $(function() {
var $strana='#'+$urlParam('id');
    $("a.test").click(function(event){
        alert($strana);
   
         
       });

And filtering shoud be done on page loading, and it is working on all browsers correctly except Google Chrome

Comment: P.S. The reason I ask is that I believe jQuery's .click() only works on events that you hooked up via .click(someHandler), so if you used an onclick attribute (or some other, non-jQuery method) to hook up your event handler, that might be your problem.

Comment: Ohhhhhh ... ok let me explain something: you can't trigger browser events with .click() (or any other event invoker for that matter).  You can cancel them by returning false inside the handler, but you can't initiate them (you can only initiate jQuery-hooked up events).  So, with that in mind ... let me reanswer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<script>
// Define event handler generator
function handleClick(url) {
    var location = url;
    return function() {
        window.location = location;
        return false;
    }
}
$(function () { // onReady
    $("A").each(function() { // connect an event handler for every A
        // Generate handler for the correct URL
        var handler = handleClick($(this).attr("href"));
        // Connect generated event handler
        $(this).click(handler);
    });
}
</script>
```

Should let you keep your existing URLs working the way they already do (for non-JS users), but for everyone else you'll have an event you trigger which does the same thing, but which is jQuery-invoke-able.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much!

Finally I figure out my mistake... I define page variable after page is loaded, so it wasn't readable for my script.

Now it looks like this:

```
     function $urlParam(name){ 
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(name) != -1) {
        var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href); 
        return results[1] || 0; 
    }
    return 0;


};
```

And after that

```
var page='#'+$urlParam('id');
if (page== '#0')
     strana ='#News';


$side_menu.find('> li > a').filter($(page)).click();
```

And now almost everything works great except Google Chrome which only select tab but don't show it content. I read here [jQuery find() returning an empty string in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680789/jquery-find-returning-an-empty-string-in-google-chrome) that it is about Chrome and HTML in Ajax.

Any tip for this or link or to make another question?

Thank you all one more time, specially machineghost!